# SwiftUI Form Bug

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I'm using SwiftUI and Form and somehow the form doesn't look like any examples. Instead it has margins and corner radiuses...I don't like this style. Is this a bug, or a new direction from Apple?

I'm using XCode 12 Beta 4

```
struct LoginView: View {
@State private var email = ""
@State private var password = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                
                SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
            }
            
            Button(action: login) {
                Text("LOGIN")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Login")
    }
}

func login() {
    let api = API()
    
    api.login(username: self.email, password: self.password) {
        ticket in
        print(ticket)
    }
}
```

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: It is not a bug - default native Form design on iOS 14. It is new (old) look&feel for Grouped List style which is used by Form. Like it or not, it is Apple.

Comment: @Asperi I saw youtube demo videos with the old form style in iOS 14 so I don't think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally get around this by changing Form to List and adding a modifier:

```
List {
    Section { }
}
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```